# didReceiveRemoteNotification not called when launched from lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm building push notifications into my iPhone app. I have the following in my AppDelegate

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    CCLogWarn(@"NOTIFICATION %@", userInfo);
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

the `CCLogWarn` method uses cocoa lumberjack under the hood to send a log to my remote logging service (papertrail)

Here's what I'm experiencing:

1. install the app on my device, the app is in the foreground
2. trigger a notification from my server and I see the info show up in papertrail, everything's good!
3. press the home button to move app to background, send another notification and see it pop up at the top of the screen. I tap it and the app launches and I see the info show up in papertrail, everything is still good!
4. press the lock button on my phone and then send another notification. When I press the lock button again to turn the screen back on, I see the notification on the lock screen and I swipe it. The app launches but I don't see anything show up in papertrail. It seems `didReceiveRemoteNotification` wasn't called.
5. I then repeat steps 2 and 3 and I don't see anything in papertrail.
6. I then force quit the app and relaunch it. I then try steps 2 and 3 and they work again (i.e. I see things appear in papertrail). But once I lock the phone again, it stops calling `didReceiveRemoteNotification` until I force quit and relaunch again.

I am sending `content-available = 1` in my notifications. I have also enabled Background Mode in the apps capabilities and I have the following in my Info.plist

```
   <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
   <array>
           <string>remote-notification</string>
           <string>fetch</string>
   </array>
```

I also have logging for the `launchOptions` dictionary in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but that isn't called when launching app from the lock screen either.

I ask this because I'd like to be go to a specific place in the app when the user gets a notification on their lock screen, I see plenty of other apps doing this and I imagine that they're relying on `didReceiveRemoteNotification` being called when the app is launched from the lock screen.